# mouseover line with some points marked

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm new to rCharts, in fact this is my first attempt. So please forgive a naive question.

I'm trying to create a simple rCharts visual which has a only one horizontal line (X-axis) and no Y-axis. I want to be able to choose the length and each point in the line has mouseover which represents some data. Also I would like to add colors to some of the special points. 
This seems very simple, but I'm having great difficulty in this.

```
library(rCharts)
age <- c(1:2000)
dot <- rep(1,2000)
name <- paste(letters[0], 1:2000, sep="")
df <- data.frame(age=age,dot=dot,name=name)
n1 <- nPlot(dot~age, data=df, type="scatterChart")
n1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key,x,y,e){var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex];return 'x:'+ x + 'y:' + y + 'name:' + d.name }!#")
n1
```

Now this will create a line with mouseover but the line in at y=1 and there are x and y axes also. I want just one line, something like a timeline with special events marked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there a reference static chart or sketch of a chart that would help us understand and visualize the objective

Comment: @timelyportfolio I couldn't find the exact copy of what I want. But the chart you get by running the above code is close, it gives a line y=1 where we can mouseover each point. What I want instead is just that line on x axis and no y axis. Also I want to mark (color differently) some special points on the line. Here is the link to the chart I got from above script. https://www.dropbox.com/s/q43jxpoxn7vtu5p/n1.html

Comment: Another example that comes to mind is a 1-dimensional scatterplot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, turning off the `y-axis` is fairly simple.  I added some other ideas to the code.

```
library(rCharts)
age <- c(1:2000)
dot <- c(
  rep(1,1000),
  rep(2,1000)
)
name <- c(
  rep(letters[1], 1000),
  rep(letters[2], 1000)
)
df <- data.frame(age=age,dot=dot,name=name)
n1 <- nPlot(dot~age, data=df, group = "name", type="scatterChart")
n1$chart(
  tooltipContent = "#! function(key,x,y,e){
    var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex]
    return 'x:'+ x + 'y:' + y + 'name:' + d.name
  }!#",
  showYAxis = FALSE,    #turns off y axis
  forceY = c(0,4)       #forces y axis to 0 min and 4 max
)
n1
```

While I think this solves the issue, I am anticipating some things.  One is if you define each point, then the data will become large.  We could change to `lineChart` to minimize data sent, but then the tooltip only shows on the points defined.  I am sure there is a way to bind an event to the path to show a tooltip then also, but it is beyond my abilities.  I would guess you might like the `x` to be a date format.  I'll be happy to demo an example of that also if you would like.

```
n2 <- nPlot(
  dot~age
  , data=data.frame(
    name = c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2)),
    dot = c(1,1,2,2),
    age = c(1,1000,1000,2000)
  )
  , group = "name"
  , type="lineChart"
)
n2$chart(
  tooltipContent = "#! function(key,x,y,e){
    var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex]
    return 'x:'+ x + 'y:' + y + 'name:' + d.name
  }!#",
  showYAxis = FALSE,    #turns off y axis
  forceY = c(0,4)       #forces y axis to 0 min and 4 max
)
n2
```

**Here is the additional code based on the comments**

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
require(rCharts)

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON('[
  [5, 
   0, "a1"], [480, 0, "a2"], [250, 0, "a3"], [100, 0, "a4"], [330, 0, "a5"],
  [410, 0, "a6"], [475, 
                   0, "a7"], [25, 0, "a8"], [85, 0, "a9"], [220, 0, "a10"],
  [600, 0, "a11"]

  ]') %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  set_colnames(c("x","y","name")) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(y))

data$grp <- c(rep("A",3),rep("B",5),rep("Z",3))

n1 <- nPlot(
  y~x
  ,group = "grp"
  ,data = data
  ,type="scatterChart"
  ,height=200
)
n1$chart(
  tooltipContent = "#! function(key,x,y,e){
    var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex]
    var mytip = [];
    mytip.push('<h1>name:'+  d.name + '</h1>');
    mytip.push('<p>x:' + x + '</p>');
    mytip.push('<p>y:' + y + '</p>');
    return mytip.join('');
  }!#",
  showYAxis = FALSE,    #turns off y axis
  forceY = c(-1,1)       #forces y axis to 0 min and 4 max
  ,showDistX = TRUE     #turn on markers on the x axis
  ,showDistY = FALSE
)
n1$yAxis(
  showMaxMin = FALSE
  ,axisLabel = NULL
)
n1
```

**note: there is a bug in the fisheye that interferes with the tooltip; we can remove to get tooltips to appear immediately**

Let me know how this works.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. This is very close to what I want. Instead of levels, I wanted the data to be on one line and there are some points marked. This is something I created in d3 https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqkgrn9rb630cix/tt.html . What I'm trying is to merge the scatter plot with x-axis and the points on scatter plot colored differently from the rest of the x-axis. Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately it might make sense to build a custom chart for this like http://mostlyconjecture.com/blog/, but I added some more code to the answer to hopefully show some other features.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @ timeyportfolio, is it possible to fix the label above each points of the graph with the nplot ? for example if I want to print out the graph it would be convenient. Thanks!

Comment: not sure I understand, so print/save the entire graph?  If so, I am not aware of any examples.  However, you might like http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/.  Ramnath developed a screenshot prototype using phantom but it runs from R/command line.